# What is wrong with this derivation of moment of inertia of a sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

I know the moment of inertia of a solid sphere is $\frac 2 5 MR^2$, but I keep getting $\frac 3 5 MR^2$ when deriving it:

For a sphere of mass $M$ and radius $R$,

$$\rho = \frac {M}{\frac 4 3\pi R^3}$$

$$I = \int_0 ^R (\rho 4 \pi r^2)(r^2) dr = (\rho 4\pi)(\frac {R^5} 5) = \frac 3 5 MR^2$$

What exactly is wrong with this?

**Edit:** This question is based on a misunderstanding of the definition of the moment of inertia.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct integral? On this page, the integral range is from -R to R. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/isph.html

Comment: @LDC3 I'm trying to integrate over each spherical shell from the center to the surface, so from 0 to R instead of integrating over each disk on an axis from -R to R.

Comment: For help, scroll down to "Moment of Inertia of a Uniform Solid Sphere – Shell Method" here: http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/old_guide/guide16Appendix.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment of inertia must be defined in terms of a [principal axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Definition). You derived it as the moment of inertia about a point while it should be calculated with respect to an axis.

Comment: In all the derivations of this I have seen, it is in fact calculated with respect to the axis, but I don't understand _why_ this does not work.

Comment: it doesn't work because you start with an infinitesimal element that is a spherical shell, and then treat ***every*** part of that spherical shell as if it were a distance $r$ from the axis, which is not true

Comment: @User58220 I am assuming you meant to say _center_ instead of _axis_. Could you explain in more detail why every part of the spherical shell is not a distance $r$ from the axis, since the shell is infinitely small, so $r$ at any point on a shell is the same, right?

Comment: No. you assume incorrectly, I think...